# How do I normalize the inside of a box in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I've read a few tutorials on normalizing in openGL and understand the concept but I'm having a hard time applying it. Can someone please check if I applied it correctly. I'm not sure which direction my camera is facing when I load in but the normals should be pointing inside the box.

```
float ver[8][3] = 
{
    {-1.0,-1.0,1.0},
    {-1.0,1.0,1.0},
    {1.0,1.0,1.0},
    {1.0,-1.0,1.0},
    {-1.0,-1.0,-1.0},
    {-1.0,1.0,-1.0},
    {1.0,1.0,-1.0},
    {1.0,-1.0,-1.0},
};

GLfloat color[8][3] = 
{
    {0.0,0.0,0.0},
    {1.0,0.0,0.0},
    {1.0,1.0,0.0},
    {0.0,1.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.0,1.0},
    {1.0,0.0,1.0},
    {1.0,1.0,1.0},
    {0.0,1.0,1.0},
};

void quad(int a,int b,int c,int d,float scaleX,float scaleY,float scaleZ )
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(ver[a][0]*scaleX,ver[a][1]*scaleY,ver[a][2]*scaleZ);
        glVertex3f(ver[b][0]*scaleX,ver[b][1]*scaleY,ver[b][2]*scaleZ);
        glVertex3f(ver[c][0]*scaleX,ver[c][1]*scaleY,ver[c][2]*scaleZ);
        glVertex3f(ver[d][0]*scaleX,ver[d][1]*scaleY,ver[d][2]*scaleZ);
    glEnd();
}

void room1()
{
    glColor3fv(color[6]);
    glNormal3d(0,0,-1);
    quad(0,3,2,1,10,5,11);//backwall
    glColor3fv(color[1]);
    glNormal3d(-1,0,0);
    quad(2,3,7,6,10,5,11); //right side wall
    glColor3fv(color[2]);
    glNormal3d(0,1,0);
    quad(0,4,7,3,10,5,11); //floor
    glColor3fv(color[3]);
    glNormal3d(0,-1,0);
    quad(1,2,6,5,10,5,11); //ceiling
    glColor3fv(color[4]);
    glNormal3d(0,0,1);
    quad(4,5,6,7,10,5,11); //front wall
    glColor3fv(color[5]);
    glNormal3d(1,0,0);
    quad(0,1,5,4,10,5,11); //left side wall
}
```

Comment: Normalizing is not defining normals on a shape. Normalizing means "bringing a vector to unit length".